# Highlight Rows of Grid based on search terms match

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a search box that allows user to type in the values they want to search the grid on. Whatever the user types in the search box should be highlighted on the grid if there is any match.
The code i'm using to try and achieve this is below:

```
const searchTerms = searchTerm.trim().split(' ').filter((item) => item !== '');
let result = rawGridRecord;
           searchTerms.forEach((val) => {
           const reText = new RegExp(val, 'gi');
           result = result.replace(reText, '<span class="text-highlight">$&</span>');
           });
```

The problem i'm having currently is that if there are more than 1 search terms, it starts to match against `'<span class="text-highlight">$&</span>'` which is now part of the `result` string. and this causes a behavior that we dont want. The html starts showing as string in the grid.

How is it possible to achieve this functionality so that all the searchTerms can be highlighted properly without creating issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const searchTerms = searchTerm.replace('*', '').trim().split(' ').filter((item) => item !== '');
const searchString = '(' + searchTerms.join('|') + ')';


let result = newName;

if (result) {
    const reText = new RegExp(new RegExp(searchString), 'gi');
    result = result.replace(reText, '<span class="text-highlight">$&</span>');
}
```

Tried this and it seems to be working better now. Not sure how full proof this is.